# JScrollBar, remove keyListener?

Tags: swing, scrollbar, jscrollpane, keylistener, arrow-keys

Hey you all, just a quick question of what i havent found anywhere. Im adding a scrollpane to a JPanel, with 2 JScrollBars. One vertical and one horizontal. Everything works fine just that i dont want the ScrollBars to scroll using the arrow keys. How do i achieve this?

I´ve been checking out adjustmentlisteners but really havent found anything of high value to me. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

you have to tweak the keybinding in the scrollPane's inputMap and point the navigation keys into nirwana, like:

```
    InputMap inputMap = scrollPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
    inputMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("RIGHT"), "do-nothing");
    // same for all navigation keys you want to disable
    ...
```

to find which keyStrokes are registered, look into the BasicLookFeel - the section in getDefaults which relates to "ScrollPane"

Beware: that's highly unusual, you user's might be annoyed!

Comment: "Beware: that's highly unusual, you user's might be annoyed!"  I smell an 'unusable GUI' in the making! ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Exactly what i was looking for :) Thing is i´ve implemented my own listener to the scrollbars so it isnt useless, just found it irritating that i had 2 listeners for pretty much the same thing, except for some events that occurs during scrolling.